# Allowing additional data to be added after a join with blank rows

Tags: sqlite

I've got a left join query that returns the correct number of rows (equal to the left table), but because the right table is empty, there are no corresponding rowid's. How can I add the rowid (RecNum should be the same value) to the empty table so that I can add data to the resulting dataset? Here's the query:

```
select
  Week01.RecNum   as RecNum,
  Week01.UserName as UserName,
  Week01.Day1Reg  as Day1Reg,
  Week01.Day1OT   as Day1OT,
  Week01.Day2Reg  as Day2Reg,
  Week01.Day2OT   as Day2OT,
  Week01.Day3Reg  as Day3Reg,
  Week01.Day3OT   as Day3OT,
  Week01.Day4Reg  as Day4Reg,
  Week01.Day4OT   as Day4OT,
  Week01.Day5Reg  as Day5Reg,
  Week01.Day5OT   as Day5OT,
  Week01.Day6Reg  as Day6Reg,
  Week01.Day6OT   as Day6OT,
  Week01.Day7Reg  as Day7Reg,
  Week01.Day7OT   as Day7OT
from
  "Project List"
left join
  Week01
on
  "Project List".RecNum = Week01.RecNum
and 
  Week01.UserName = "JustMe"
```

or, if that can't really be done, how about a query that will pre-create row entries in Week01 (if they don't already exist) to match the same RecNum column and fill in the username with "JustMe"? But, the thing is that if the RecNum already exists in Week01, it can't be overwritten. Any ideas on that? If that could be done, then the query above should work out just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually select it using `IFNULL`

```
 SELECT
 IFNULL(Week01.RecNum, "Project List".RecNum
 ..
```

To answer your question of getting all recNums that exists in project List but not in Week01
you can do use `left join`

```
select p.RecNum
from "Project List" p
left join Week01 w
on p.RecNum = w.RecNum
where w.RecNum is NULL
```

or you can use `not exists` clause

```
select p.RecNum
from "Project List" p
where not exists
(  select 1 from Week01 w
   where p.RecNum = w.RecNum
)
```